# Sql Cursor....not adding data into the temporary created table

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor

I have the below cursor. It generates the right set of statements but I am not able to insert the data into the temporary created table. The cursor is as below. Please have a look.

```
--use a cursor to get the stats
  use qcsiteadmin_db0

-- Declare the variables needed
   DECLARE @DOMAIN_NAME VARCHAR(255)
   DECLARE @PROJECT_NAME VARCHAR(255)
   DECLARE @DB_NAME VARCHAR(60)
   DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(max)
   DECLARE @COUNTSQL NVARCHAR(2000)
   DECLARE @FOLDER VARCHAR(255)
   ---DECLARE @FILTER VARCHAR(500)

   select @FOLDER = 'System Validation'

   -- Create a Temp Table
  CREATE TABLE #defects(
  DOMAIN_NAME VARCHAR(255),
  PROJECT_NAME varchar(255), 
  DEFECT_NUMBER int,
  SUMMARY VARCHAR(255),
  ASSIGNED_TO VARCHAR(255),
  DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(8000),
  STATUS VARCHAR(255),
  PRIORITY int)


  --Declare the Cursor for looping the database calls
  DECLARE qc_dbs CURSOR  FOR
  select DOMAIN_NAME,PROJECT_NAME,DB_NAME
  from td.PROJECTS
  where PR_IS_ACTIVE = 'Y' 
  and DOMAIN_NAME not in
  ('mk_conversion', 'default','other','z_archivedprojects','sqa')
  order by DOMAIN_NAME,PROJECT_NAME

  --For each valid QC database get the defect counts needed
   OPEN qc_dbs
   FETCH NEXT FROM qc_dbs INTO @DOMAIN_NAME,@PROJECT_NAME,@DB_NAME
   WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
   BEGIN               


   select @SQL = 'select  ''' + @DOMAIN_NAME + ''', ''' + @PROJECT_NAME + ''', ' + @DB_NAME       + '.td.bug.BG_BUG_ID, ' + @DB_NAME + '.td.bug.BG_SUMMARY,  ' + @DB_NAME + '.td.bug.BG_RESPONSIBLE, 
                     ' + @DB_NAME + '.td.bug.BG_PRIORITY
                     from ' + @DB_NAME + '.td.CYCL_FOLD ' +
  ' INNER JOIN  ' + @DB_NAME + '.td.bug on  '
  + @DB_NAME + '.td.CYCL_FOLD.CF_ASSIGN_RCYC =  ' + @DB_NAME + '.td.BUG.BG_DETECTED_IN_RCYC 
  and ' + @DB_NAME + '.td.CYCL_FOLD.CF_ITEM_NAME = ''' + @FOLDER + ''' and ' + @DB_NAME + '.td.BUG.BG_STATUS = ''New'' '

  print @SQL

  BEGIN TRY
        insert into #defects
        execute (@SQL)
  END TRY
  BEGIN CATCH
  print 'Error accessing' + @DOMAIN_NAME + '.' + @PROJECT_NAME 
  END CATCH;


  FETCH NEXT FROM qc_dbs INTO @DOMAIN_NAME,@PROJECT_NAME,@DB_NAME
  END

  -- Close the Cursor
  CLOSE qc_dbs
  DEALLOCATE qc_dbs

  --Select from Temp Table
  select 
  DOMAIN_NAME,PROJECT_NAME,
  DEFECT_NUMBER,SUMMARY,ASSIGNED_TO,DESCRIPTION,
  STATUS, PRIORITY
  from #defects

  -- Destroy the Temp Table
  Drop TABLE #defects
```

---

My output messsages look like -

```
select  'ADMIN_SYSTEMS', '1099Process', admin_systems_1099process_db.td.bug.BG_BUG_ID,      admin_systems_1099process_db.td.bug.BG_SUMMARY,  admin_systems_1099process_db.td.bug.BG_RESPONSIBLE, 
                       admin_systems_1099process_db.td.bug.BG_PRIORITY
                     from admin_systems_1099process_db.td.CYCL_FOLD  INNER JOIN  admin_systems_1099process_db.td.bug on  admin_systems_1099process_db.td.CYCL_FOLD.CF_ASSIGN_RCYC =  admin_systems_1099process_db.td.BUG.BG_DETECTED_IN_RCYC 
  and admin_systems_1099process_db.td.CYCL_FOLD.CF_ITEM_NAME = 'System Validation' and admin_systems_1099process_db.td.BUG.BG_STATUS = 'New' 

 (0 row(s) affected)
 Error accessingADMIN_SYSTEMS.1099Process
```

Please have a look.

Regards.

Comment: You are catching the exception and printing out a fairly useless message.  Try removing the `BEGIN TRY` and `END TRY` lines, and the whole `CATCH` block, run the script and give us the error message.  Or just run the SQL statement that is printed out in the output messages and give us the error from that.

Comment: Thanks....i got the error & was able to sort it out.